# Check If Users are Logged In, Check Condition, Shutdown Automatically at Set Time

Tags: 10.04, server, ssh, samba, shutdown

First the situation:

I have a server that I want to shutdown automatically at night (00:00), but I need to make sure no one is logged via ssh in still. If they are, then I will allow up to another hour for a second shutdown attempt (01:00) at which time the server goes down no matter what.

I figure I can just go with a cron job for shutdown (unless there's a better way to schedule shutdowns), but wouldn't know how to implement the check in the first case.

Extra:

Is there a way to know if a user is actively using his samba share, and in this case, not complete the shutdown procedure. Or better yet, check if there is a healthy amount of Disk I/O that will also not complete the shutdown.

I have seen some answers already that can help me out, so I wish to know specifically, what would be the best way to accomplish this as a whole, without hacking up different bits and pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for active connections with:

```
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep ":[portname] " | wc -l
```

- Port 22 is for ssh connections.
- Port 445 is for samba connections.

So add this to a bash script and add the bash script to a cronjob.

1. Creating a cronjob:

   ```
   sudo su
   crontab -e
   ```

   Insert something like this for a check at 24:00 and a forced shutdown at 01:00:

   ```
   # Check for shutdown system at 24:00 every day
   00 0 * * * /usr/bin/shutdown_script
   # Shutdown at 01:00 every day
   00 1 * * * /usr/bin/shutdown -h now
   ```
2. Create the script (still as root ;) ):

   ```
   gedit /usr/bin/shutdown_script
   ```

   and add in the commands you want to check for:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   users_ssh=`netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep ':[445] ' | wc -l`
   users_ssh_alertvalue="0"
   if [ "$users_ssh" -eq "$users_ssh_alertvalue" ]; then
        /sbin/shutdown -h now
   fi
   ```

   and ofcourse make it executable.

You can make this more refined by adding more options to the `if` all you need to do is find the correct command to find the value you want to check. I have not (yet) found a nice I/O check though (`iostat` and `iotop` look promising).

edit:
while looking for a I/O check command I found `mpstat`. It reports processors related statistics (see `man mpstat`). CPU idle time from `mpstat`:

```
mpstat | grep all | sed -s 's/.* all// ; s/ * / /g' | cut -d ' ' -f10
```

So you could add this in and shutdown when CPU idle time is higher than 98%.

Comment: I don't know why I assumed this would be anything but this, but I had to ask. I guess that's the price we pay for the power of linux! Thanks for pointing me in a narrower direction. Really like the completeness of this answer.

Comment: well the sed and grep parts are difficult yes but it isn't all bad (most of these things are doing a good google search :D )